# Bokeh TapTool, How to use multiple TapTools

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I have two datasources and want to select them seperatly with the TapTool. When I click on the circle, it redirected me to a web page. This works for one plot, but I can't get it to work for two diffrent plots.
I´ve tried the add_tool function, but it doesnt work at all.

```
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=df1["xPos"].values,
    y=df1["yPos"].values,
    url=df1["Url"].values
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=df2["xPos"].values,
    y=df2["yPos"].values,
    url=df2["Url"].values

plot = figure(width= 500, height= 500, tools="pan,wheel_zoom,save,reset,tap", 
              x_range=Range1d(-10.1, 10.1), y_range=Range1d(-10.1, 10.1), title='TapToolTest')

plot1 = plot.circle('x', 'y', size=20, source=source1)
plot2 = plot.circle('x', 'y', size=10, source=source2)

url = "@url"
#taptool = plot.select_one(TapTool)
#taptool.renderers = [plot1]
#taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url) #This methode works, but only for plot 1

plot.add_tools(TapTool(renderers=[plot1], callback = OpenURL(url=url)))
plot.add_tools(TapTool(renderers=[plot2], callback = OpenURL(url=url)))

show(plot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have 1 plot and 2 renderers. The code below works fine for all circles (as of Bokeh v2.1.1):

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, OpenURL, TapTool
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           tools="tap", title="Click the Dots")

source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, ],
    y=[2, 5, 8, ],
    color=["navy", "orange", "olive", ]
    ))
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[4, 5, 6],
    y=[2, 7, 4],
    color=["firebrick", "gold", "skyblue"]
    ))

p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=20, source=source1)
p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=30, source=source2)

url = "http://www.colors.commutercreative.com/@color/"
taptool = p.select(type=TapTool)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)

show(p)
```